# Postgres ON DELETE Rule Not Working With WHERE Clause

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to implement "Soft Deletes" given the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE categories(
  id serial not null primary key,
  num integer,
  "name" text,
  deleted_at timestamp default null
);

CREATE OR REPLACE RULE delete_categories AS
  ON DELETE TO categories
  WHERE old.deleted_at IS NULL
  DO INSTEAD
    UPDATE categories SET deleted_at = NOW()
    WHERE categories.id = old.id;
```

The expected behavior is that if I try to delete a record with a NULL deleted_at value, it will instead be set to the current timestamp.  If I try to delete a record with a non-NULL deleted_at value, it will be deleted normally.

Instead, running the below sequence returns no records, instead of a record with a timestamp in the deleted_at column:

```
insert into categories(num,name,deleted_at) values(9999,'Test Category',null);
delete from categories;
select * from categories;
```

It appears as though the RULE does not get triggered at all, and the record is simply deleted, whereas if I modify the RULE by commenting out the WHERE clause, the record is updated as expected but I am barred from being able to delete it fully:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE delete_categories AS
  ON DELETE TO categories
  -- WHERE old.deleted_at IS NULL
  DO INSTEAD
    UPDATE categories SET deleted_at = NOW()
    WHERE categories.id = old.id;

insert into categories(num,name,deleted_at) values(9999,'Test Category',null);
delete from categories;
select * from categories;
```

Results:

```
+----+------+---------------+----------------------------+
| id | num  |     name      |         deleted_at         |
+----+------+---------------+----------------------------+
|  3 | 9999 | Test Category | 2015-03-03 20:05:44.660208 |
+----+------+---------------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: Is the table named `categories` or `cats`?

Comment: It's categories, I made a typo in the question and copy/pasted it forward.  I updated the question to fix it.

Comment: This seems like a bug to me. If you run `delete from categories WHERE deleted_at is null;`, your rule has the desired effect.

Comment: That's very strange.  Is the `WHERE old.deleted_at IS NULL` in the rule actually referencing the `DELETE` query criteria, rather than the affected row?

Comment: As an alternative I could leave out the `WHERE` and use an `IF/ELSE` check on `deleted_at` to decide between an update or delete, but I can't find any examples of using plpgsql in a rule, only triggers.  I'll see if I can put together a trigger version.

Comment: No, I think it's more complicated. You could try playing with `INSTEAD OF` triggers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The manual in [Rules on INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rules-update.html)) describes the INSTEAD mechanism for the context of your rule as:

> Qualification given and INSTEAD
>
> the query tree from the rule action with the rule qualification an
>   the original query tree's qualification; **and the original query
>   tree with the negated rule qualification added**

Overlooking the part emphasized above would be the cause of the unexpected result.
I believe that in your test case, the mentioned DELETE will be transformed by the rule into commands to the same effect as:

```
UPDATE categories SET deleted_at = NOW()
    WHERE categories.id = categories.id AND deleted_at IS NULL;

DELETE from categories WHERE NOT old.deleted_at IS NULL;
```

The DELETE removes the row because the UPDATE before it has just set its `deleted_at` field to non-null.

Note also the `categories.id = categories.id` condition which is obviously not needed and comes from the misunderstanding that `OLD` does not reference a specific row like in a trigger, it's meant to be replaced by the table subject to the rule.

The main point to understand is that rules don't look themselves at the rows and so they don't generate a kind of IF-THEN-ELSE construct depending on the row contents. The WHERE clauses of the RULES (the qualifications) are not evaluated by the rule system, they are injected into the commands produced by the rule system and will be evaluated by the commands themselves.

See also [What are PostgreSQL RULEs good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894142) and links within for some interesting insights on rules and why they're hard to use.

Comment: The explanation looks perfectly fine, +1. The behaviour/implementation though looks totally buggy and ill-determined. Why the 2 sub-rules that the rules is transformed are executed in this order and not the opposite one? Is there a way to tell from before?

Comment: And does this "rewrite" seems like a good solution/bypass of the specific issue of the OP? **[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0d1d3/5)** Seems to work fine in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at triggers and came up with the following alternative to the rule:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_delete_cat() RETURNS trigger as $$
  BEGIN
    IF old.deleted_at IS NULL THEN
      UPDATE cats SET deleted_at = NOW() WHERE cats.id = old.id;
      RETURN NULL;
    ELSE
      RETURN OLD;
    END IF;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_delete_cat BEFORE DELETE ON cats 
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_delete_cat();
```

This gives the desired results, but as I'm still wondering what I did wrong with the rule I'll refrain from accepting this answer.